# How phpmyadmin authentication works?

Tags: mysql, apache, authentication, phpmyadmin

I would like to know why I dont have a first authentication asked to phpmadmin itself, before get to mysql authentication.

I set my admin password like this :

```
 htpasswd /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup admin
```

And this is my **/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf** file :

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

#Alias /ionis_rda /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

                php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
                php_flag track_vars On
                php_flag register_globals Off
                php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
                php_value include_path .
                php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
                php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
                #AuthName "admin"
                AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
       </IfModule>
       Require valid-user
</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
    AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
    </IfModule>
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

And I create a specific vhost for phpmyadmin. But when I enter the url I get directly to the database connection banner like shwon on the picture below [image].

My question is it how it works or I forgot something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue by moving this:

```
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
 #AuthName "admin"
 AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
 Require valid-user
```

to the phpmyadmin vhost configuration instead of

Regards.